# Inserting the tags in the middle of the string in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have the code which iterates through every character in string from a cell in first worksheet, checks whether it is formatted (bold, underlined, coloured) and put my custom tags (eg. {b} and {eb}) in right position and paste it to another cell in second worksheet. I can't figure out how to make my tags appear in the right place. I tried out with LEFT and RIGHT, MID functions, but didn't succeed.

```
Dim b, u, c As Boolean
Dim x As Integer

b = False
u = False
c = False

Dim bytes() As Byte
Dim example As String

example = FCTitle.Offset(0, 1).Value
bytes = example

   If FCTitle.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "" Then
    Debug.Print "start"

       For x = LBound(bytes) To UBound(bytes) Step 2
            With FCTitle.Offset(0, 1).Characters(x, 1)

               If .Font.Bold = True And b = False Then
                    s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value = s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value & "{b}"
                    b = True
                    Debug.Print s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value

            End If
            If .Font.Underline = 2 And u = False Then
                s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value = s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value & "{u}"  '
               u = True
                Debug.Print s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value
            End If
            If .Font.ColorIndex > 0 And .Font.ColorIndex <> 1 And c = False Then
                s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value = s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value & "{c}" ' & Right(bytes, UBound(bytes) - x)
               c = True
                Debug.Print s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value
            End If
            If (.Font.ColorIndex < 0 Or .Font.ColorIndex = 1) And c = True Then
            s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value = s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value & "{ec}"
                c = False
                Debug.Print s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value
            End If
            If .Font.Underline <> 2 And u = True Then
                s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value = s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value & "{eu}"
                u = False
                Debug.Print s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value
            End If
            If .Font.Bold = False And b = True Then
                s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value = s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value & "{eb}"
                b = False
                Debug.Print s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value
            End If
            If Asc(.Text) = 10 Then
                s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value = s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value & .Text
                Debug.Print s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value
            End If

        End With

      Next x
        If c = True Then
        s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value = s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value & "{ec}"
        Debug.Print s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value
        c = False

        End If
        If u = True Then
        s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value = s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value & "{eu}"
        Debug.Print s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value
        u = False

        End If
        If b = True Then
        s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value = s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value & "{eb}"
        Debug.Print s1Title.Offset(-1, 1).Value
        b = False

        End If
        Debug.Print "koniec"     
    End If
```

So far values printed in console after each change in string look like below. Word "SUPER" is bolded, underlined and coloured red, so my expected output should be "{b}{u}{c}SUPER{eb}{eu}{ec} aaa {b}{u}{c}SUPER{eb}{eu}{ec}". Sorry if I did something wrong, it is my first post here.

```
start
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}{c}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}{c}{eu}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}{c}{eu}{ec}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}{c}{eu}{ec}{eb}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}{c}{eu}{ec}{eb}{b}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}{c}{eu}{ec}{eb}{b}{c}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}{c}{eu}{ec}{eb}{b}{c}{u}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}{c}{eu}{ec}{eb}{b}{c}{u}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}{c}{eu}{ec}{eb}{b}{c}{u}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}{c}{eu}{ec}{eb}{b}{c}{u}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}{c}{eu}{ec}{eb}{b}{c}{u}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}{c}{eu}{ec}{eb}{b}{c}{u}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}{c}{eu}{ec}{eb}{b}{c}{u}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}{c}{eu}{ec}{eb}{b}{c}{u}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}{c}{eu}{ec}{eb}{b}{c}{u}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}{c}{eu}{ec}{eb}{b}{c}{u}{ec}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}{c}{eu}{ec}{eb}{b}{c}{u}{ec}{eu}
SUPER  aaa  SUPER{b}{c}{ec}{u}{c}{eu}{ec}{eb}{b}{c}{u}{ec}{eu}{eb}
koniec
```

Comment: It would help a lot to provide a sample of your *expected* output... We don't really know exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: My expected output should be "{b}{u}{c}SUPER{eb}{eu}{ec} aaa {b}{u}{c}SUPER{eb}{eu}{ec}".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me (written as a UDF)

[image]

Some of the character properties are a bit tricky - for example `Bold` can be `null`, `False`, or `True`, and `ColorIndex` doesn't seem that reliable.

```
Function Coded(r As Range)
    Dim rv As String, b As Boolean, c As Boolean, u As Boolean
    Dim bC As Boolean, cC As Boolean, uC As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, txt

    For i = 1 To Len(r.Value)
        'get this character's properties
        With r.Characters(i, 1)
            bC = Not (IsNull(.Font.Bold) Or .Font.Bold = False)
            uC = (.Font.Underline = 2)
            cC = (.Font.ColorIndex <> -4105) '-4105=automatic
            txt = .Text
        End With
        'opening or closing any tags?
        If c <> cC Then
            rv = rv & IIf(cC, "{c}", "{ec}")
            c = cC
        End If
        If b <> bC Then
            rv = rv & IIf(bC, "{b}", "{eb}")
            b = bC
        End If
        If u <> uC Then
            rv = rv & IIf(bC, "{u}", "{eu}")
            u = uC
        End If
        rv = rv & txt
    Next i

    'close any open tags
    If b Then rv = rv & "{eb}"
    If c Then rv = rv & "{ec}"
    If u Then rv = rv & "{eu}"

    Coded = rv
End Function
```

Comment: Straight copy/paste of your code doesn't seem to work. Maybe not the latest version?  Line 11:  `.Text` is not a property of `Characters.Font`  Also, don't get the same output as you show with the same data.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld - my bad, that's what i get for making edits after posting: fixed.  Your output may vary on the "color" tag: as noted that seems to be a little finicky.

Comment: Looks good now.  And the differing outputs were because my default font color was **black** rather than **automatic**, so the entire string was being seen as coloured.